# How to remove a form label that is not showing in the form file?

Tags: forms, symfony, label

I'm working on some form collections from the cookbook, however I have this label that appears and I'm trying to remove this without any luck.

I don't see the code below listed in my forms.

How can I remove this label?

The highlighted in blue label 'Clientphones' is what I'm trying to remove:

[image]

This is the label in page info:

[image]

ClientPhone form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('home', 'text');
    $builder->add('office', 'text');
    $builder->add('mobile', 'text');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\ClientPhone',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'ClientPhone';
}
```

Client form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'First Name'
        ))
        ->add('lastName', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Last Name'
        ))
        ->add('email', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'E-mail Address'
        ))
        ->add('clientphones', 'collection', array(
            'type'         => new ClientPhoneType(),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ));
}
```

Twig form

```
<form class="form" name="client" method="post">

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.firstName) }}
    {{ form_row(form.lastName) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}

    <h3>Client Phones</h3>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="clientphones" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.clientphones.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {% for phone in form.clientphones %}
            <li>{{ form_row(phone.home) }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_row(phone.office) }}</li>
            <li>{{ form_row(phone.mobile) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    {{ form_end(form) }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the field to rendered before your `{{ form_rest(form) }}` so it doesn't try to render everything that has been missed (intentionally or otherwise).

```
    {% do form.clientphones.setRendered %}
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Comment: Perfect, hides that label! Had no idea about this. What does this do exactly and where I read more about this?

Comment: Each form field is a `FormView` (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormView.php) object with a `$rendered` property. I assume that when you call something like `{{ form_row() }}` it automatically sets rendered to true meaning it doesn't get picked up in the `{{ form_rest() }}` pass. I only found out about the `{% do ... setRendered %}` from StackOverflow rather than any documentation so I can't really help you beyond that.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for that explanation Qoop! And yeah the same for me, did some searching and only found references from StackOverflow regarding the `{%do ... setRendered %}` command.

Answer (score 0):

Use form_label, form_error, form_widget instead of form_row

e.g.

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(phone.home) }} // remove or update this if you want to drop or modify the label
    {{ form_errors(phone.home) }}
    {{ form_widget(phone.home) }}
</div>
```